# Remove lines that is shorter than 5 characters before the @ using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Maybe the title is 99% not understandable

I have like that:

```
abc@5004428
abcd@62604
abcde@505779
```

But my file is larger than that.

So, I want to remove the whole line that contain "abc" and "abcd" becase they are before @ and they are shorter than 5 or not equal characters.

More explained: I want to remove the whole line which value before @ is shorter than or EQUAL to 5 characters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you have written a program to do this or you want to do it in notepad++ manually?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - Notepad++ manually.

Comment: in which case, im pretty sure this is off topic

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - I see there's a lot of questions regarding Notepad++ on Stackoverflow.

Comment: however, the question you are asking is nothing to do with coding, its to do with an ide so its not exactly on topic

Comment: Try regex like this: `^(.{0,4}@.*)$`

Comment: @DariaPydorenko - It worked perfectly! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex like this: `^(.{0,4}@.*)$` to select lines and then remove them with Notepad++.

`^` - a start of the line

`.{0,5}` - checks if value before `@` is shorter than or equal to 5 characters.

NOTE: `.{0,4}` will check if value before `@` is shorter than 5 characters (not equal to 5 characters).

`.*` - all other symbols after `@`.

`$` - an end of the line

Comment: 0,4 marked only 50 line, while 0,5 marked 107 line like the answer of @JohnDoe

Comment: 0,4 marked all lines, which `shorter than 5`, and 0,5 - `shorter than 5 or equal to 5`

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant or equal 5 too. it is my mistake I forgot to state that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Set 'Search Mode' to regular expression, and use the following phrase:

^\w{1,5}@.+

works like this:

^-       : start of line

\w{1,5}  : 1 to 5 word charachters long

@        : matches 'At sign' literally

.+       : remainder of line

and replace with empty line.
To replace empty lines set search mode to extended and replace double line ends with single line ends.