# Remove lines that is shorter than or equal 5 characters after the : using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

The question is like: [Remove lines that is shorter than 5 characters before the @ using Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463273/remove-lines-that-is-shorter-than-5-characters-before-the-using-notepad)

But it differs a bit...

I have like that:

> abc:123
>
> abc:1234
>
> abc:12345

***PLEASE NOTE***: `abc` is not on all the lines, it is just an example.

I want to remove the `first` line in the previous example because `123` which is after `:` is shorter than or not equal to 5 characters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: So wouldn't that be *Remove lines that are shorter than 9 characters* (`abc: ` + the five digits)?

Comment: @KenWhite No, the lines differ and not simple like the example.

Comment: @emsimpson92 - Notepad++ - no programming languages, it is a regex question.

Comment: Then [edit] your question  provide more detail and more *actual* examples of what should (and should not) match. Don't expect us to know things that you've not mentioned in your post.

Comment: If that is all you want to do you can use `regex.replace(line, ".*:\d{0,5}", "");` Regex doesn't seem like the answer here though.

Comment: ***PLEASE NOTE***: `abc` is not on all the lines, it is just an example.

Comment: I updated it. Now it doesn't matter how many characters are before the `:`

Comment: @emsimpson92 - So it is not possible to do with a regex?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but there is probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Notepad++ `find and replace` choose `regex` mode in the search and place `^((?!.+:\d{5,}).)*$` in search and keep replace with blank and press replaceAll

> ^((?!.+:\d{5,}).)*$

Comment: I was unaware you could use regex with find and replace. That's quite the handy feature!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the language there is only so much help I can offer. I'll give you an example of how I would solve this problem in C#.

Start by creating a string for your updated file (without the short lines)

`string content = "";`

Read a line in from your file.
Then get a substring of the line you read in - the abc: portion and check the length.

```
line = line.substring(indexof(":"), length - indexof(":"))
if(line.length > 5)
{
  content += line;
}
```

At the end, truncate your file and write content to it.