# Remove the lines that have characters less than 8 after the : using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have like that

> abc2:12345678
>
> ab50:1234567
>
> clo:123456789

In the previous example, the **second** line should be removed because the characters after the `:` are less than 8 characters.

I tried a lot to get the regex but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: We'd like to see your attempts.

Comment: @revo `^((?!.+:\d{7,}).)*$` But it remove a lot of wrong lines.

Comment: How about `^[^:]*:.{0,7}$`?

Comment: @revo - It worked great! You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Why do you ask twice the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50954452/372239

Comment: @Toto - The answer on the other question is not working, and I was not able to add any comments or edits to the old question (I don't know why).

Comment: So, why did you accept an answer if it is not working?

Comment: @Toto - the answer on the previous question is working rarely on some examples, that's why I accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to match lines with maximum 7 characters after colon would be:

```
^[^:\n\r]*:.{0,7}$
```

If they are supposed to be digits:

```
^[^:\r\n]*:\d{0,7}$
```

You may also want to remove following newlines:

```
^[^:\r\n]*:\d{0,7}(?:\R+|$)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/7TjfwP/1)